# MultiValueDictKeyError 'name'

Tags: python, django

I have few apps in my project and now Im stuck with following problem, when Im filling up all fields and pressing "submit" then following error is showing:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at / 'name'
Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:     3.1.2
Exception Type:     MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:    

'name'
```

Views form main directory(which is colliding `name = request.POST['name']`):

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST['name']
        email = request.POST['email']
        subject = request.POST['subject']
        message = request.POST['message']

        send_mail(
            'message from' +' '+ name +' '+ email,
            message,
            email,
            ['blablablabla@gmail.com'],
            fail_silently=False,
        )

        return render(request, 'wwwapp/home.html', {'name': name})
    else:
        return render(request, 'wwwapp/home.html')
```

I think with this views:

```
def become_vendor(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()

            login(request, user)

            vendor = Vendor.objects.create(name=user.username, created_by=user)

            return redirect('frontpage')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()

    return render(request, 'vendor/become_vendor.html', {'form': form})


@login_required(login_url='loggin')
def vendor_admin(request):
    vendor = request.user.vendor
    product = vendor.products.all()

    return render(request, 'vendor/vendor_admin.html', {'vendor': vendor, 'product': product})


@login_required
def add_product(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            product = form.save(commit=False)
            product.vendor = request.user.vendor
            product.slug = slugify(product.title)
            product.save()

            return redirect('vendor_admin')
    else:
        form = ProductForm()

    return render(request, 'vendor/add_product.html', {'form': form})
```

Forms for this Model:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from product.models import Product


class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['category', 'image', 'title', 'description', 'price']
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem does not come from the data you're sending ? Your code looks ok to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I find out to do to get through this error but from my point of view this isnt the best solution because my email system had to be commented otherwise i Im having another error... But when I passed form 1st time and uncommented my code everything is fine back again !

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        subject = request.POST.get('subject')
        message = request.POST.get('message')

        # send_mail(
        #     'message from' +' '+ name +' '+ email,
        #     message,
        #     email,
        #     ['artur199933@gmail.com'],
        #     fail_silently=False,
        # )

        return render(request, 'wwwapp/home.html', {'name': name})
    else:
        return render(request, 'wwwapp/home.html')
```